# Printing lines from a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, readfile

When I start printing lines from a file, I get this error

```
#<File:0x007ff65ee297b0>
```

Here is the code

```
require 'rubygems'
File.open("sample.txt", 'r') do |f|
puts f
end
```

Comment: that is not an error. It is printing the file object

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way :

```
IO.foreach("sample.txt") {|line|  line }
```

Or

```
File.foreach('sample.txt') {|line| line }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the file object. To get the contents line by line, you can use `File.foreach`

```
File.foreach('sample.txt', 'r') do |line|
  puts line # called for every line
end
```

To process the whole file at once, you can use the `read` method on the file object:

```
File.open('sample.txt', 'r') do |file|
  puts file.read # called only once
end
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is not an error**. It prints correctly one line which is your File object.
Here your create a file object and you did not ask it to fetch lines or anything else for that matter.

Several good answers already. But here is another way to do it with minimal change to your code:

```
File.open("sample.txt", 'r').each_line do |f|
  puts f
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[`File::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-open) returns file handle (which apparently is being printed out as `#<File:0x007ff65ee297b0>`.) If you need the file content line by line you might want to use [`IO::readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-c-readlines):

```
IO.readlines("sample.txt").each do |line|
  puts line
end
```